# How to create a Menu like this that show us contents

Tags: html, css, store

Helo guy how are you?

I'm a younger developer that I be improve my knowledges, then right now I was travel over the internet when I finded a website very cool https://www.jinx.com With this i will try to develop something menu equal that website, but unfortunately it was in vain :(

I'm still learn a lot of HTMl, CSS, JQ and whaterever web lenguages... Could somene help me to create a menu bar like this?

Greatful now!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. In this case: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Comment: I think you should try to do it yourself. If you have a specific issue people can help you but this isn't a place for people to build something from scratch for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use inspect in chrome(F12).You can see the css in the right corner.Make use of it.
[image]
You can follow the google devTools for Live-edit ,changes will be reflected in UI. Live-edit style property names and values in the Styles pane. All styles are editable, except the ones that are greyed out (as is the case with user agent stylesheets).

To edit a name or value, click on it, make your changes, and press Tab or Enter to save the change.

Follows this: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/

Hope it helps.!

Comment: @FelipeSantos,That's fine. Try it. If the solution was found helpful,mark it up vote. Click tick mark in left .